# Witcher 2 Gargoyles: How to get in the last district?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The question is all in the title. I'm talking about the district on the left of gate when you arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure where you are but I guess this:

Amphitheater area is accessible from the hallways leading out the far side of the town square. Along the amphitheater, head to the right and you'll find a room where gargoyles attack

[Here is full quest guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/The_Gargoyle_Contract)

Map

[image]

Video guide